# How to get support for paid software from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, support

After buying and installing a game via the Ubuntu Software Centre, I find the software does not work. But where do I turn to for support?

The game company says it does not support its game ported to Linux as they seemingly where not involved in that. Ubuntu does not seem to provide support unless I pay for it (again) and it seems totally unfair to bug the user community with this issue. I've paid for the software after all...

There is a serious flaw in how Canonical has integrated free and paid software into one app store type thing, without transparent support info (where to get it) for paid software.

Or am I missing something here??

Comment: What software are we talking about? Did you not get an email as [Warrioring64](http://askubuntu.com/a/112843/25863) explained?

Comment: It's a game by MumboJumbo: Midnight Mysteries: Devil on the Mississippi

Comment: And the error I get:

Lua script executedPanic error in file "/home/ubuntu/Shared/HotSource_v5/HotEngine/Common/OpenGL/OpenGLTexture.cpp", line 687:
  Failed to create OpenGL texture (error code: 0x500, size: 500x256 -> 512x256, format: 7)
Aborted

Comment: Hmm...you may want to [file a bug](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/18612), but I'm not sure if there's any special steps that need to be taken for paid software.

Comment: ubuntu-bug tells me it cannot gather information since it's not an original ubuntu package... but I'll bugfile on launchpad anyway to see if that gets me anywhere. Any tips about what info to include there? Thanks :)

Comment: UPDATE: although the package page for mm3 is available on launchpad bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mm3 and I could start filing the bug against it, during the process I got the error that the package mm3 "does not exist in Ubuntu" and I need to choose another package. When I do that, I see the package mm3 listed as option but selecting that, I get the same error message. Feel a bit caught in some kind of crazy loop here. All in all, my first purchase via USC is a very disappointing experience. I think Ubuntu should rethink their policy in this respect. :(

Comment: UPDATE2: filed bug against unknown package https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/956530

Answer (score 3):

When I got commercial software from the Ubuntu Software Center in 11.10, I was sent an email for each one providing a troubleshooting link in case of issues (different for each package installed). Try checking the inbox of your email account that you use with Ubuntu SSO.

Comment: Yes, I did get that e-mail and following the link, I find myself on a very vague message that says "To install packages from this archive you need to copy the line below and add it to your system's software sources." followed by a line that I copied over to the software sources... After that, nothing. The page does not explain anything else and updating does not get me any new packages or anything.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Sorry about this,  the Mumbo Jumbo games won't work on intel gfx we have got onto the developers to update the description to include this information.  This is not a linux/windows issue but one with the intel hardware and one unfortunately we can do nothing about.

Please goto https://software-center.ubuntu.com/subscriptions/ copy the details for the app then goto https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Pay/FAQs/Refunds follow the steps there and add those details with the fact that you are trying to run it on intel gfx and it is failing.  You will be given a refund.

We the Software-Center Team are working to stop this from happening in the future sorry again for any hassles that you've had.